# google chrome with jquery and php login damaged

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

i have problem with jquery working in chrome . 
i have a code ( login code ) it works correctly in mozilla firefox but in chrome the output is "1" ;

here is all codes - the php part

```
<?php
session_start();
define('toDay',date('Y-m-d H:i'));
define('lib','lib/');
include lib.'config.php';
include lib.'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' and       pass='$pass' limit 1");
    if( $u = $db->fetch($sql)){
        if($u['sath']=="modir"){
        $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['id']    = $u['id'];
        $_SESSION['time']  = time();
        $_SESSION['name']  = $u['name'];
        echo 1;}
        else{
        $_SESSION['user'] = true;
        $_SESSION['id']    = $u['id'];
        $_SESSION['time']  = time();
        $_SESSION['name']  = $u['name'];    
        echo 1;
        }

    }else{
    echo "رمز عبور یا ایمیل اشتباه می باشد .";  
    }
}
else {
    echo "لطفا جاهای خالی را پر کنید";
}
die();
}

?>
<!doctype html>
```

the html part and jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<!-- Apple devices fullscreen -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<!-- Apple devices fullscreen -->
<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap responsive -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- Color CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes.css">


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/migration.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/eakroko.js"></script>

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
<!-- Apple devices Homescreen icon -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
<script>

</script>

</head>

<body class='login'>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-big.png" alt="" class='retina-ready' width="59" height="49">تحلیلگران امین</a></h1>
    <div class="login-body">
        <h2>ورود کاربر</h2>
        <form id="login-form" method="post">
            <div class="email">
                <input type="text" name='uemail' id="uemail" placeholder="آدرس ایمیل" class='input-block-level'>
            </div>
            <div class="pw">
                <input type="password" name="upw" id="upw" placeholder="رمز عبور" class='input-block-level'>
            </div>
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="ورود به پرتال مشتریان" class='btn btn-primary'>
            </div>
            <div class="_response">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="forget">
            <a href="http://www.tgaco.ir/"><span>بازگشت به وبسایت تحلیلگران امین</span></a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {


    $("#login-form").submit(function(){
    var uemail = $("#uemail").val();
    var upw = $("#upw").val();

        $.post('index.php',{email:uemail,pass:upw},function(data){
            if(data){

                    if(data == 1){
                        document.location.href = "admin/index.php"; 
                    }
                    else {
                    alert(data);
                    }

            }
        });
         return false;
    });

 });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Verify that there is no trailing space or something that would mess up the if-condition. ie. `console.log('"' + data + '"')`

Answer (score 0):

Both time you `echo 1;`

```
 if( $u = $db->fetch($sql)){
    if($u['sath']=="modir"){
    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['id']    = $u['id'];
    $_SESSION['time']  = time();
    $_SESSION['name']  = $u['name'];
    echo 1; //<=== HERE
  }
  else{
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['id']    = $u['id'];
    $_SESSION['time']  = time();
    $_SESSION['name']  = $u['name'];    
    echo 1; //<=== HERE
  }
```

That's why you getting 1 for result

Comment: but i change the values but chrome alerts the number !!

it should redirect to page not alerting the number but in mozilla that redirects to page.

Comment: Try `window.location = "admin/index.php";` instead of `document.location.href = "admin/index.php";`